# Docker registry space if pushing two images from same docker file

Tags: docker, docker-registry

What happens on docker registry server space side when an image is created from same docker file. So, for example in case below, if I push an image with tag 1.0 and then create another image with same docker file and push that with tag 1.1. Is it going to take any additional space on docker registry?

```
docker build . -t myRegistry.com/myImage:1.0
docker push myRegistry.com/myImage:1.0

docker build . -t myRegistry.com/myImage:1.1
docker push myRegistry.com/myImage:1.1

docker build . -t myRegistry.com/myImage:1.2
docker push myRegistry.com/myImage:1.2

docker build . -t myRegistry.com/myImage:1.3
docker push myRegistry.com/myImage:1.3
```

Comment: Did you try this? It should basically tell you what happens - it will use the same image, which is calculated by the image's sha256 value -- the tag is an alias to that unique image. It's a one-to-many relationship, i.e., you can have many tags point to the same image.

Comment: thanks.. even if docker build is run from different machines? e.g. one build & push is from machine-1 and another build & push is machine-2 .. does it checks sha256 with docker-registry before pushing?.. Trying to understand it better.

Comment: If the output of the build results in the same hash, it will recognize it as the same image. If the build actually results in the same hash depends on a [number of factors](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28826)

Comment: On top of what has been already said, an image typically consists of several layers and it is possible to share just some of the layers. So even if the image is different, some space may be shared.

Comment: thanks a lot... @ldg if you can post summary in answer section. I can mark question answered.

Comment: np @KumarGaurav. summary posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample case, the container registry will use the same image, which is calculated by the image's sha256 value (also known as the `IMAGE ID`) -- the tag is simply alias to that unique image.

It's a one-to-many relationship, i.e., you can have many tags point to the same image. You can use `docker images --no-trunc` to see the full value of the IMAGE ID. (Note this is useful if you have consistency issues using common tags like "latest" or "develop" since you can't be sure which image it actually is unless you use the sha256 value.)

For builds on different machines/environments, using the same Dockerfile with the same files *may* result in the same hash, but it [depends on many variables](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28826) like how dynamic your dependencies are, if timestamps have changed, etc.

As @Henry mentioned, this further applies (largely behind the scenes) to individual layers of an image:

> Docker images have intermediate layers that increase reusability,
>   decrease disk usage, and speed up docker build by allowing each step
>   to be cached. These intermediate layers are not shown by default.

[see docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/images/)

Btw, to see a *container*'s sha256 value to see which *image* it came from, you can `inspect` it, e.g., `docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' mongo:3.4-jessie`